# Ajax success callback is not invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I pass `function() { location.reload(); }` as a callback - it doesn't get invoked.

```
$('#swapLanguageLink').click(function() {
    $.post('@Url.Action("SwapLanguage", "Language")', function() { location.reload(); });
    //location.reload();
});
```

If I un-comment `//location.reload();` (instead of passing callback) - it works nice, but I am not sure if it is async or not.

It can happen that my document will be reloaded before async operation is finished, right? So why my callback doesn't work?

---

Edit:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SwapLanguage", "Language")', null, function () { 
    location.reload();
}).done(function () {
    location.reload();
}).error(function () {
    alert('error');
});
```

I've tried the code above. `error` get invoked. But "SwapLanguage" invokes. Something really strange to me!

Comment: Can you try `$.ajax` to have full control over ajax request?

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan does it mean that the only thing I need to change is to put `$.ajax('#swap...')`?

Comment: `$.post('@Url.Action("SwapLanguage", "Language")', null, function () { location.reload(); })
                .done(function () { location.reload(); })
                .error(function () { alert('error'); });` heh.. I've tried the code above... error get invoked. But "SwapLanguage" invokes... Something really strange to me!

Comment: If the `error` callback is invoked it means the Ajax call returned with an error status. Look at the error.

Comment: @Tomalak I am totally new to the ajax... the debug breakpoint in VS does nothing. How can I see the error details?

Comment: Use the browser's developer tools. Look at the network tab. Instead of `alert('error');` use `console.log(arguments);` and look at the console. Set breakpoints in your JS code and inspect variables. Javascript debugging 101, that's not really Ajax-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: '@Url.Action("SwapLanguage", "Language")',
    success: function (data) {
       location.reload(); 
    },
    error: function (err)
    { 
      alert("error");
    }
});
```

OR

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SwapLanguage", "Language")', null)
  .done(function(data) {
     location.reload(); 
  });
```

Comment: .erorr invokes.. but at the same time targeted controller method (SwapLanguage()) - runs too. so I get waht I need making .always(...). But  it seems to be strange...

Comment: What error comes in your browser? Open `debugger` in your browser and check for errors in `console`